# Sharing data between 2 web apps

Tags: web-applications, database-design, soa

I am working on a new app(App 2), i already have a existing app (App 1) with decent user base.

App 2 is targeted at same user base, a user can use any one of the apps or both of them, how can i share user data (multi entities) across apps?

option 1  - shared database sounds like a bad idea, as i will end up writing validation rules at 2 different place.

options 2 - central service and datastore will mean re writing most of app 1 which is working well and the code base is pretty huge.

options 3 - treat App 1 datastore as central datastore and expose it as API. App 2 can use this to read and write data. i still have few questions for this solution -

- App 2 is now dependent on App 1 which means App 1 issue affects App 2. I can solve this by caching data in App 2. This results in other problems.
- Data changed in App 1 is not reflected in App 2 immediately which is one of the requirements. i can solve this by pub/sub model between App 1 and App 2.
- App 2 always writes data to App 1 datastore using API and i can push data back to App 2 but then its not consistent rather it is eventually consistent.
- App 2 writes data to its own datastore and then it is pushed to App 1 asynchronously. This result in data conflict issues.

How can i handle this problem without introducing huge complexity in both my apps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents.

The easiest approach would be for your to share the same database, and since you referred that the database can be shared it means that the domain rules from App1 still apply to App2, and even if there are some differences it is better to write those changes than writing the whole thing.

Now, you do have a big issue IMO, because if I understood it well, you don't have a proper service layer, because if you did, you could actually make any changes to the DAL without affecting the existing 1.

Before I can go any further I actually need to know a bit more of your current architecture, otherwise I end up making wrong assumptions.

- What kind of Web Application framework are you using e.g.: ASP.Net MVC
- Have you got a service/API Layer and what about Domain and DAL layers?

**UPDATE**

So your existing App is built in PHP, what if you extract the REST API from the App 1 and place it in a brand new PHP solution (site) which could be shared among the App 1 and App 2 as a Service API? I believe that this would be the easiest way for you to do.

Comment: 1. Both apps are written in php. 2. I do have a restful API for App 1. I am worried about performance of App 2 if i use it directly in App 2.

Comment: You should not even do that, I mean making App 2 use Api 1. Would you be able to extract the REST API from App 1?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have all the details on your situation, but I'd tend to move to a solution where you'd have a new service that handle the users and both apps would use that.

That said, it doesn't have to be a big bang move. you can start by adding a proper API on top of the users data in app1. and make app2 use that. Then you can add an abstraction layer in app1 that talks to the new API and looks like App1 internal APIs to APP1 and only then move the data to a new database which will be the new service